# Stop dll from using the exe.config file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I have a C#.NET dll which gets plugged into the main executable which is built from VC++ code(not targetting .NET).This main exe has an exe.config file which is just used as normal xml file(using non validating parser).But problem comes when some internal code(oledbconnection) in dll tries to load the config file and because it finds this config file as invalid , it crashes. I dont even need any of the values in exe.config file, so i can safely ignore that. 
So what i need to do here is either stop dll from using the exe.config or tell dll that its valid config file(even if its not). How can i do this? or is there any other way?

PS : I cant change the exe.config file and make it as valid file

Comment: Do you have the source code of the VC++ project?

Comment: yes, i do have source code of vC++ project. But as i said i can't change xml config file or the parsing code in that.

Comment: All the ".config" files are for .net applications as we have "machine.config" or "web.config". If your .NET dll is using the file, existance of it is not necessary. You can delete the file, but I think you're reading the config file from the C++ code. Is it correct?

Comment: You could check solutions mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466098/reading-and-writing-values-in-net-config-files